# New route not working (2.2)

Tags: magento2.2, routing

I am frustrated. I'm unable to add an ajax route in Magento 2.2 no matter what I try, I get a 404.

routes.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="schematics" frontName="schematics">
            <module name="Schematics" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
        <route frontName="schematics_ajax" id="schematics_ajax">
            <module name="Schematics" before="Magento_Adminhtml"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

The Controller is beside working controllers at [module path]/Controller/Adminhtml/Ajax/Index.php and looks something like this:

```php
//namespace is defined here.
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        die('foo');
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        die('foo');
    }
}
```

/admin/schematics_ajax/index shows a **404**

I'm pretty sure I followed https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/routing.html pretty much exactly. What am I missing?

Comment: try `/admin/schematics_ajax/ajax`

Comment: check if it works

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed it and got the route standing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>      
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">      
   <router id="admin">      
      <route id="schematics" frontName="schematics">      
          <module name="Schematics" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />      
      </route>      
      <route frontName="ajax" id="ajax">      
          <module name="Schematics"/>      
      </route>      
   </router>      
</config>
```